# Need to call aspect without xml configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

I want to run an aspect in spring without using xml file.
I have written the classes as below and AOPTest class is my junit test case which calls the method showProducts(), but before calling showProducts()
i need to call the aspect logBeforeV1(..) which is not being called in my code below. Any inputs would be appreciated.

```java
package com.aop.bl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.aop.bl")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyBusinessLogicImpl {
    public void showProducts() {
        //business logic
        System.out.println("---show products called from business layer----");
    }
}
```

```java
package com.aop.bl;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.aop.bl.MyBusinessLogicImpl.showProducts(..))") // point-cut expression
    public void logBeforeV1(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("------------calling showProducts() from MyAspect---------------: ");
    }
}
```

```java
package com.aop.test;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.aop.bl.*;

public class AOPTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyBusinessLogicImpl myObj = new MyBusinessLogicImpl();
        myObj.showProducts(); 
    }
}
```

My ouput is as below:

```
---show products called from business layer----
```

Expected output :

```
------------calling showProducts() from MyAspect---------------:
---show products called from business layer----
```

Note: I have enabled aspect using **`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`**

Answer (score 0):

Your unit-test is launched out of spring context, so you need to import your configuration

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyBusinessLogicImpl.class })
public class AOPTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the update, What is SpringRunner.class  @Nikolay Shevchenko

Comment: @user3684675  Spring's implementation of JUnit's Runner

Comment: ok..I will try calling from main() method and test without using @RunWith..

Comment: Shevchenko - I have added as you mentioned above..but still it is not calling the Before  in MyAspect class